# What is the proper format for RowKey column in WADWindowsEventLogsTable (Azure Diagnostic Extension)

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have configured **Azure Diagnostic Extension** and it works fine.

[image]

I can see **WADWindowsEventLogsTable** with event data.

As I can see `RowKey` format for these data is:

```
f4384921-7e24-4b71-9971-095352aa990d___IaaS____WindowsServer01___0000000004295488675

{Deployment Id}___IaaS____{Server Name}___{Timestamp}
```

Please pay attention in this format I see **4 underscores** after "IaaS" prefix. But other places contains **3 underscores**.

Also I have reviewed many links and I see always 3 underscores in the `RowKey` parts:

- https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-and-controlling
- https://novacontext.com/microsoft-azure-security-and-audit-log-management/index.html
- https://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/

Unfortunately all links that I have found it is not official Microsoft documentation. I can't find official documentation about correct format for this data. And I'm afraid sometimes used **3 underscores** (as example for ScaleSets or CloudRoles) and sometimes used **4 underscores** (as example for ARM VM).

I need to develop universal code for all possible situations. So for me it is very critical understand correct `RowKey` format.

For me it is very strange why only after "IaaS" prefix I see 4 underscores.

Could someone explain what format for `RowKey` is correct?

---

*Thanks for any help.*